# charsetName java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, mysql, json

I m trying to get data from server in JSON form.But While doing so I'm getting errors in log cat as..

> 01-09 15:15:35.463: E/Buffer Error(28006): Error converting result
> java.lang.NullPointerException 
>  01-09 15:15:35.463: E/JSON
> Parser(28006): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input
> at character 0 of

This is my code,

> try {
>
> ```
>         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
>                 is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
>         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
>         String line = null;
>         while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
>             sb.append(line + "\n");
>         }
>         is.close();
>         json = sb.toString();
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
>     }
>
>     // try parse the string to a JSON object
>     try {
>         jObj = new JSONObject(json);
>     } catch (JSONException e) {
>         Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
>     }
>
>     // return JSON String
>     return jObj;
> ```

Comment: Add the exception to your log calls to get helpful stacktrace about the actual problem. That is, add `, e` at the end of your log calls.

Comment: It looks like you're getting empty message in JSON. Are you sure the message sent by server is not empty?

Comment: I am first time working on webservices...if i run my php file in browser i can see data in browser

Comment: @PiotrChojnacki i am first time working on webservices...if i run my php file in browser i can see data in browser

Comment: string is coming from server....problem is handled..now i can see data while running my app on emulator but while running it on device i got exception..i m passing this url ("myIpAddress:80/SVDP/getDate.php/")

Comment: i m done by keeping it on live server